# Copy TR element and append to external source if checkbox is marked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('button#btnBuscar').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.post(Routing.generate('filtrarNormas'), $('#buscadorNorma').serialize(), 'json')
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.entities.length > 0) {
                    $('#resultadoNorma').show();

                    var $html = '';
                    data.entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
                        $html += '<tr>';
                        $html += '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' + value.id + '"></td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.codigo + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.norma + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.anno + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.comiteTecnico + '</td>';
                        $html += '</tr>';
                    });

                    $("table tbody#resultadoNormaBody").html($html);
                }
            })
            .fail();
});
```

The purpose of the code above is to execute a Ajax call and render many `tr` as values get in JSON response, this works fine. Now as you can see there is a checkbox on the first column on each iteration, right?

What I need to do is copy the complete row (tr) when the current checkbox is checked and append, without repeat the same content and without erase the other table content, to another table. There might be a lot of possible solutions but right now (according to @josh-kg) suggestion one of them could be mark the checkbox and instantly clone the current `tr` element and it will work, yes, but what happen if I toggle the checkbox several times? The same row will be append to `#newTable` and is not the idea. Using this solution provided, then I should toggle the clone to in order to append/remove the cloned `tr`.

I was thinking in have a button (`button#btnAplicarNorma`), disabled by default, and if I have at least one checkbox marked, then enable it and on click event of the button do the clone part by iterating over each marked checkbox, something like:

```
$('button#btnAplicarNorma').on('click', function (ev) {
    // check if at least there is one checkbox marked and enable the button 
    // check which checkboxes are marked and clone the current element 
})
```

But how can I do this?

Note: The table where `tr` should be clone isn't in the modal itself but in the same page so this shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#resultadoNormaBody').on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){ 
    var my_checkbox = $(this);
    if (my_checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        my_checkbox.closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#newtable');
    }
});
```

UPDATE (after OP made some clarifications on the intended behavior):

To have the button disabled by default, include the disabled attribute in the HTML tag:

```
<button id="btnAplicarNorma" disabled>Copy Rows</button>
```

Then, to enable the button when at least one checkbox is checked:

```
$('#resultadoNormaBody').on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){

        var $my_checkbox = $(this);
        var $my_tr = $my_checkbox.closest('tr');

        if ( $my_checkbox.prop('checked') ) {

                // Add the class to mark that it should be copied later when button clicked
                $my_tr.addClass('copyMe');

        }

        var $all_checkboxes = $my_checkbox.closest('tbody').find('input[type=checkbox]');

        // Loop through checkboxes to see if one is checked

        $all_checkboxes.each(function() {
            // if one checkbox is checked, enable button and end the .each loop

            if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {

                $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled',false);
                return false;

            } 

            // If we didn't catch any checked boxes earlier, disable the button

            $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled',true);

        });

});

$('#btnAplicarNorma').on('click', function (ev) {

    var $tr_to_append = $('#resultadoNormaBody').find('tr.copyMe');

    // is there's a tr to copy, clone it, append, and remove the copyMe classes
    if ( $tr_to_append.length ) {
        // first uncheck all the checkboxes
        $tr_to_append.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
        // copy and append and remove class
        $tr_to_append.clone().appendTo('#newtable').removeClass('copyMe');
        $tr_to_append.removeClass('copyMe');
        // disable the button again
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    }

});
```

Comment: your solution will work, yes, but what happen if I toggle the checkbox several times? The same row will be append to `#newTable` and is not the idea, if I leave as you suggest then I should toggle the append part to and I have don't know, my idea is to have a button (sorry for do not mention on the main post) and mark all the checkboxes I want to append and then on click event of the button append them to the new table, something like `$('button#btnAplicarNorma').on('click', function (ev) { // check what checkboxes are marked and clone the current element });` how?

Comment: Well that's a different question, go ahead and edit your original and I'll edit my answer!

Comment: done, take a look and tell me if this is enough and thanks for your answer

Comment: it works perfectly just one thing, the `clone()` copy exactly the `tr` element as it is and that include the checkbox marked, can I unmark the checkbox in somehow before pass to the second table?

Comment: also I notice that your code only works for just one `tr` what about if I want to copy more than one?

Comment: good catch, I made some edits to resolve the "only one tr" problem and remove checks before cloning -- see if that works

Comment: it's not working, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/wq51zL9x/) a fiddle with your code and a functional example

Comment: Ok in your example you should be appending to the tbody element appendTo('#normaBody'). You'll also need to add some functionality to close your lightbox and show your hidden table. Otherwise it looks like its working.

Comment: Ohhh you're right I miss that part on the copy/paste and yes changing from `#tablaNorma` to `#normaBody` does the code work, one last thing: it's possible to no repeat the cloned element? What I mean, if you add the same element, lets say the second row (tr) each time you open the modal then it will be added. I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/wq51zL9x/1/) with working example and for close the modal you can use ESC key or close in the header X button